# I can't figure out how to use JButton Action

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

*Hello, I'm new in Java. I can't figure out how to use JButton Action. Hi, I'm new to JAVA and I need some help. The goal of my training task is to create a table with a button that could also create tables with data, and then combine the selected data. But I'm faced with probably a very simple problem ,I do not know how to set the action on the button , or rather how to make the button just draw a class . My code is below.*

That is my main method:

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFJB JaFr = new JFJB();
    JaFr.JFJB();
}
```

}

JFrame+JButton:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

 public class JFJB extends JFrame {

// JPanel/Frame
JPanel pnlFrameforButton = new JPanel();
// JButton
JButton btnMakeTable = new JButton("MakeTable");




public void JFJB() {       
   
    
    // FlightInfo setbounds
    btnMakeTable.setBounds(60, 400, 220, 30);

    // JPanel bounds
    //pnlButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 5, 5));
    pnlFrameforButton.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
    

    // Adding to JFrame
    pnlFrameforButton.add(btnMakeTable);
    add(pnlFrameforButton);

    // JFrame properties
    setSize(350, 200);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setTitle("Just Frame with Button");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

The class I want to draw:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


 public class PlayerTable extends JFrame {

 public static void createPlayerTable() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test frame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      String[] columnNames = {
                "Name",
                "Score"
      };
       
      
      String[][] data = {
                {"addins", "02.11.2006 19:15", "Folder", ""},
                {"AppPatch", "03.10.2006 14:10", "Folder", ""},
                {"assembly", "02.11.2006 14:20", "Folder", ""},
                {"Boot", "13.10.2007 10:46", "Folder", ""},
                {"Branding", "13.10.2007 12:10", "Folder", ""},
                {"Cursors", "23.09.2006 16:34", "Folder", ""},
                {"Debug", "07.12.2006 17:45", "Folder", ""},
                {"Fonts", "03.10.2006 14:08", "Folder", ""},
                {"Help", "08.11.2006 18:23", "Folder", ""},
                {"explorer.exe", "18.10.2006 14:13", "File", "2,93MB"},
                {"helppane.exe", "22.08.2006 11:39", "File", "4,58MB"},
                {"twunk.exe", "19.08.2007 10:37", "File", "1,08MB"},
                {"nsreg.exe", "07.08.2007 11:14", "File", "2,10MB"},
                {"avisp.exe", "17.12.2007 16:58", "File", "12,67MB"},
      };
       
      JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
       
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
       
      frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 200));
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

}

Comment: Beginners should start with [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

```
btnMakeTable.addActionListener(e -> {
   PlayerTable.createPlayerTable();
});
```

also in ur main method u don't need the second line since the constructor is already being called and it is not static

you could also implement the interface actionlistener and use addActionListener(this);

Comment: *"also in ur main method u don't"* This is a technical forum, not a text message. Spell words like 'you' and 'your' fully.

Comment: bruh chill I'm just tryna help a dude out from my phone i don't wanna type that much. why does it matter as long as he understands what to do.